# Android resource for a specific product

Tags: android, android-resources, android-x86

i got this code from Settings app...

```
<string name="about_settings" product="tablet">About tablet</string>
<string name="about_settings" product="default">About phone</string>
```

then my questions are:

1. from where at runtime the system load the correct string resource ?
2. What must I do to add a new product? e.g.

   ```
   <string name="about_settings" product="laptop">About laptop</string>
   ```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. from where at runtime the system load the correct string resource ?

The system does not load this at runtime. The correct string resource is preloaded according to PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTICS defined for a specific target build. So you cannot use this while building from eclipse. This is used only for building apps preloaded on platform.

> 2 . What must I do to add a new product? e.g.

You need to add to PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTICS in device.mk file

Comment: Was looking through source and stumbled on the same thing. Out of curiosity, where did you learn the origins of this `product` attribute? From working on custom ROMs? I assume that's where you would preload apps.

Answer (score -1):

Answer for your question 1.
You can get them via

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

But your `strings.xml` should something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="tablet" >About tablet</string>
    <string name="default" >About phone</string>
 </resources>
```

Answer for your question 2.
How will that work, because that is a resource file. If you want you can either create a file and save the information in it. Locally. But it will be only on that device.

Comment: Your answer for the question 1 is not what i need, from my previous example i guess that the value for the attribute 'product' is compared with the value stored on /sys/class/dmi/id/uevent and then is selected the right resource.