# Gradle build fails due to duplicate entry in strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, gradle

In my current Android project strings the mentioned below are used based on product:

```
<string name="insert_sd_card" product="nosdcard">"Por favor, inserte una tarjeta SD"  </string>
<string name="insert_sd_card" product="default">"Por favor, inserte una tarjeta SD"</string>
```

When I ran the Gradle build (tried with 0.7, 0.8, 0.9), I'm getting the following error:

> *\res\values-es\strings.xml: Error: Found item String/insertsdcard more than one time

Comment: Probably this question will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995503/android-resource-for-a-specific-product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), an XML string attribute "name" is used like a resource ID by the Android system. In other words, you cannot have two strings with the same "name" attribute, even if they differ in other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you'll need to use per-flavor based configuration to achieve your needs - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/iKy-umAQpAc

Comment: Note, this question is about a Gradle build error. Please read the SO guidelines (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), especially the "Answer the question" section.

Comment: @C0D3LIC1OU5 this is the only correct answer here; despite it is link-only.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you named same value two times

`<string name="insert_sd_card"` and  `<string name="insert_sd_card"`

just rename one of the `'insert_sd_card'` to any other name like `'place_sd_card'`

So, <`string name="insert_sd_card"` would become `<string name="place_sd_card"`

It may work.